# How to track scroll to which div position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to track scroll to which div position? when div height not fixed and not sure(from db select), how to make if scroll to each div then do something ...

should I store each div position push into array then if scroll position in array  then scroll to key div? but this seems will be crash…..

```
<div class="1">1</div> // 10px height
<div class="2">2</div> // 13px height
<div class="3">3</div> // 11px height
… // … height
```

Comment: You can monitor how far down someone is scrolled by using the `window.scroll` event. Inside the event handler do two things: 1. Throttle the event handler so it doesn't fire every single time the `window.scroll` event fires (because it can crash your site). 2. Get the current scroll position with `$(window).scrollTop()`. You can then compare that value to the offset of the divs using `.offset().top`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, my problem is not every div same height and there's a lot div,   should I store each height and push array  then if scroll top in array position fires? but this seems will be crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All elements have an offset when the DOM loads.

If you want to push all of the tops into the array, do like below.  Then when your scrolling, compare the window scroll position to the arrays.  If it matches an array number, do what you want with that array number.  **This is untested code, but the theory is there**

```
var divTops = [];  //Start an empty array
$(document).ready(function(){  //When the DOM loads
    $('div').each(function(e){ //For each div
        var top = $(this).offset().top; //Get its top
        divTops.push(top);  //and push that top into the array
    });
});

$(window).scroll(function(){  //When the user scrolls
    var scrolled = divTops.indexOf($(window).scrollTop());  //get the index number 
    if(scrolled === 0){  // Use the index number to control whatever is there.
        //Do something with the first div
    } else if(scrolled === 1){
        //Do something with the second div
    } else if(scrolled === 2){
        //Do something with the third div
    } else {

    }
});
```